# XML to string to save in SQL (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, xml, string

I got a simplexml variable wich stores an xml file, what i need to do is convert it to a string and then save it in a SQL database file, i tried:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

but it only shows me the content of the labels, and i need to get all the structure to save it.

Is there any way to get te full string from an XML variable in PHP ??

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the rest of the code as the single line of code provided does echo out the entire XML as a string.

Comment: Something's wrong with your `$xml`, as `$xml->asXML();` *will* do what you're asking.

Comment: when do you say "string" do you mean JSON? or just take the .xml and make simply a string? in that case why not file_get_contents($xml_file); ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as someone said herem, simply using the

```
$test = $xml_variable->asXML();
```

it will store the entire xml in $test variable, only problem is that when you echo it it will show you only the label value, not the label itself. this is why i tought it wasnt working.

Anyway i updated the xml field in my sql table and it fills it with a well formated xml string .

Answer (score 0):

You can use php xml parse function.

php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php#87920

```
    <?php
function xml2array($url, $get_attributes = 1, $priority = 'tag')
{
    $contents = "";
    if (!function_exists('xml_parser_create'))
    {
        return array ();
    }
    $parser = xml_parser_create('');
    if (!($fp = @ fopen($url, 'rb')))
    {
        return array ();
    }
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $contents .= fread($fp, 8192);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents), $xml_values);
    xml_parser_free($parser);
    if (!$xml_values)
        return; //Hmm...
    $xml_array = array ();
    $parents = array ();
    $opened_tags = array ();
    $arr = array ();
    $current = & $xml_array;
    $repeated_tag_index = array ();
    foreach ($xml_values as $data)
    {
        unset ($attributes, $value);
        extract($data);
        $result = array ();
        $attributes_data = array ();
        if (isset ($value))
        {
            if ($priority == 'tag')
                $result = $value;
            else
                $result['value'] = $value;
        }
        if (isset ($attributes) and $get_attributes)
        {
            foreach ($attributes as $attr => $val)
            {
                if ($priority == 'tag')
                    $attributes_data[$attr] = $val;
                else
                    $result['attr'][$attr] = $val; //Set all the attributes in a array called 'attr'
            }
        }
        if ($type == "open")
        {
            $parent[$level -1] = & $current;
            if (!is_array($current) or (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current))))
            {
                $current[$tag] = $result;
                if ($attributes_data)
                    $current[$tag . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level] = 1;
                $current = & $current[$tag];
            }
            else
            {
                if (isset ($current[$tag][0]))
                {
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level]] = $result;
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    $current[$tag] = array (
                        $current[$tag],
                        $result
                    );
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level] = 2;
                    if (isset ($current[$tag . '_attr']))
                    {
                        $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag . '_attr'];
                        unset ($current[$tag . '_attr']);
                    }
                }
                $last_item_index = $repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level] - 1;
                $current = & $current[$tag][$last_item_index];
            }
        }
        elseif ($type == "complete")
        {
            if (!isset ($current[$tag]))
            {
                $current[$tag] = $result;
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level] = 1;
                if ($priority == 'tag' and $attributes_data)
                    $current[$tag . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
            }
            else
            {
                if (isset ($current[$tag][0]) and is_array($current[$tag]))
                {
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level]] = $result;
                    if ($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes and $attributes_data)
                    {
                        $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                    }
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    $current[$tag] = array (
                        $current[$tag],
                        $result
                    );
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level] = 1;
                    if ($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes)
                    {
                        if (isset ($current[$tag . '_attr']))
                        {
                            $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag . '_attr'];
                            unset ($current[$tag . '_attr']);
                        }
                        if ($attributes_data)
                        {
                            $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                        }
                    }
                    $repeated_tag_index[$tag . '_' . $level]++; //0 and 1 index is already taken
                }
            }
        }
        elseif ($type == 'close')
        {
            $current = & $parent[$level -1];
        }
    }
    return ($xml_array);
}
?>
```

Comment: this returns me a php array, inst it ?? what i need is a string with all the tags etc to store it in my database as a string

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try DomDocument:

```
$xml = new DomDocument();
$xml->loadXML($xml_str);
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

for reference: http://us.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php

Comment: i got my xml stored in a PHP variable $my_xml

tried this but it doesnt work:

$xml = new DomDocument();
$xml->loadXML($xml_cliente);
echo $xml->saveXML();

Comment: sorry, I changed my answer. loadXML() takes a string of xml, not a filename.